# Angular app not calling a php

Tags: php, angular, http, post

So, I have a simple crud Angular web application and for some reason when i try to do an http.post to a php nothing happens. Sorry but i know nothing about web apps and php and i have to deliver this.

Service that contains the call (basically the line that calls the post php is in the update method, but i include all the file because i dont know if there is something wrong elsewhere):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DbService {

    public headers:Headers;

    constructor(public http:Http) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }

    getStock(){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost/api/stock/read.php').map(res => res.json());
    }

    getSales(){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost/api/ventas/read.php').map(res => res.json());
    }

    updateDB(member:string){

        let data:Data;
        data = {name:member};
        console.log(data.name);

        this.http.post('http://localhost/api/productos/create.php', 
        JSON.stringify(data), 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: this.headers
        });
    }
}

interface CarrItem{
    id: number,
    name: string,
    price: number,
    stock: number,
    quantity: number
}

interface Data{
    name: string
}
```

And this is the php, it works when used in a web browser, i knw cause it inserts correctly into the database.

```
<?php
    // required headers 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Accept: application/json;");

    require '../config/database.php';


    $m_name = "20:23";


    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    if(strlen($m_name)>0){
        $insertMember = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO member(membershipType, firstName, lastName, sex, birthDate, accumulatedPurchases) values('Dorada', ?, 'M', 'Other', '2018-1-1', 50.0)");
        $insertMember->execute(array($m_name));
        $otra = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO brand(brandName) values('SI')"); 
        $otra->execute();
    }
    else{
        $otra = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO brand(brandName) values('NO')"); 
        $otra->execute();
    }

    Database::disconnect();
?>
```

Comment: Try it just passing the data object as is, without using JSON.stringify on it. I don't know which version of Angular you're running but with Angular 4 I just pass the JSON object in the post and it gets serialized automatically. I tried to find the section of the docs that refers to that but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: What means nothing happens? The post request in the console was fired? There was a 40x or 50x error code? Did you watch the console?

Comment: I´m using the newest version of Angular, i tried sending it without the stringify but remains the same.

Comment: With nothing happens i mean that the database ramains un chaged.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it is working in your browser because you are doing a GET (not a POST) and you are not using any request parameters in your code above.  As-is, your code will run into problems getting the request data.

POST-ing JSON data to PHP is a little complex.  PHP will not automatically parse the data for you.  Instead, you'll have to do something like ...

```
$jsonEncoded = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonDecoded = (array) json_decode($jsonEncoded, true);
```

INSTEAD OF THAT, MIGHT BE EASIER ... to just let Angular send the data in old-style `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format and let PHP auto-parse it into `$_POST` for you.

```
let body = new URLSearchParams();
body.set('name', member);
body.set('age', 28);
this.http.post(my_url, body);
```